# Error in saving variable as txt file , matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a variable 'result' of size 170 rows and 1024 columns. I want to save this as txt file with each column separated by tab. Any ideas

```
path = 'E:\Data\fault\300';
s = what(path);
matfiles = s.mat; 
l = numel(matfiles);
for a = 1:l
  file = fullfile(path,char(matfiles(a)));
  load(file);
  result(:,a) = signal(1:1024);
end
save('300_faults.txt','result');
```

but the text in the file appears to be with this error

```
MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Thu Mar 02 11:55:20 2017                                        
ð×r   A¶Ñ†�P´’2ÔÙ„=éfŠg^k£m!zÐ~nžöNÁo7]‡üWî£¡÷É�;>Ñ¯ñ™˜
```

how to correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the [`-ascii` flag](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#inputarg_fmt) when using `save` otherwise a binary .mat file is saved

```
save('300_faults.txt', 'result', '-ascii')
```

As a sidenote, whenever loading data from a `.mat` file using `load` you should always use an output argument to avoid naming conflicts with your local workspace. Also you can specify the variables you would like to load as additional inputs to `load`

```
data = load(file, 'signal');
result(:,a) = data.signal(1:1024);
```